# ARMv8-A, Raspberry Pi 3b GIC/Timer Initialization

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to write an embedded OS and am emulating a Raspberry Pi 3b on QEMU. Currently, I am stuck trying to enable timers and interrupts. I have looked at the documentation [here](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/bcm2836/bcm2836-peripherals.pdf), which is the datasheet for the BCM2836/BCM2837.

I have tried writing value 0x300 to memory address 0x40000000, which is the base address of the GIC and also the address of the 64-bit timer control register. I have also given it a prescaler value and ostensibly enabled interrupts and routing. However, reading the locations at 0x4000001C and then 0x40000020, which are the LSB 32 and MSB 32 bits of the timer respectively, does not give me any data at all.

```
/*
*************************
** BCM2837 Timer Setup **
*************************
*/
.equ TimerAddress,          0x40000000
.equ TimerCtrlVal,          0x300
.equ TimerPrescalerAddr,    0x40000008
.equ TimerPrescalerVal,     (1 << 32)
.equ TimerRWLSBAddr,        0x4000001C
.equ TimerRWMSBAddr,        0x40000020
.equ CoreTimerIntAddr,      0x40000040
.equ CoreTimerIntVal,       0x00000003
.equ Core0Mailbox0,         0x400000C0
.equ AxiCounter,            0x4000002C
.equ LocalTimerCtrlAddr,    0x40000034
.equ LocalTimerCtrlVal,     0x3F000000
.equ LocalIntRoutingAddr,   0x40000024
.equ LocalIntRoutingVal,    0x00000000
.equ LocalTimerClearAddr,   0x40000038
.equ LocalTimerClearVal,    0xC0000000

.global _enable_timer
_enable_timer:
    ldr     x0,     =TimerAddress
    ldr     x1,     =TimerCtrlVal
    str     w1,     [x0]
    ldr     x0,     =TimerPrescalerAddr
    ldr     x1,     =TimerPrescalerVal
    str     w1,     [x0]
    ldr     x0,     =CoreTimerIntAddr
    ldr     x1,     =CoreTimerIntVal
    str     w1,     [x0]
    ldr     x0,     =LocalTimerCtrlAddr
    ldr     x1,     =LocalTimerCtrlVal
    str     w1,     [x0]
    ldr     x0,     =LocalIntRoutingAddr
    ldr     x1,     =LocalIntRoutingVal
    str     w1,     [x0]
    ldr     x0,     =LocalTimerClearAddr
    ldr     x1,     =LocalTimerClearVal
    str     w1,     [x0]
    ret
```

While debugging this code in gdb, I have been able to verify that the code is running and then drop myself into a basic `for {}` loop in assembly to watch for incoming interrupts (I have a valid interrupt vector already set up).

This is all running in EL3, and no interrupts are ever provided by the timer. What am I missing to enable interrupts from the arm_timer?